# Remove anchor tag from meta box link

Tags: metabox

i've created my own metabx. You can select items (shortcodes) from my plugin und these shortcodes return html code. 
How can i remove the complete a-Tag from my own meta-box content?

meta_box

```
add_meta_box(
        'name',
        __('NAME'),
        array( Plugin_WP_NAME_Navigation, 'nav_menu_link'),
        'nav-menus',
        'side',
        'low'
    );
```

filter

```
 add_filter('wp_nav_menu', 'do_shortcode');
```

output

```
<li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-1008" class="menu-item menu-item-type- menu-item-object- menu-item-1008"><a title="HTML CODE HERE</li>
```

i don't need the a-tag

Comment: The third parameter is a callback function that should echo the content of your meta box. I guess the problem starts there.